# NodeJS Application not responding after a certain time period

Tags: node.js, lua

Okay so, I am getting 524 Error on my nodeJS Application after a period of it being up and being used, I let it run it for 24h and haven't sent it a request, and it was working fine, but after 1 hour of that I tried to send a response, I am getting 524 error. Here is a link to my nodeJS Application https://lynxclient.com/luaparse/, I have contacted my hosting and this is what they provided

> Thank you for the update. If you face a resource usage issue and hitting a limit (for example, in your case, we see high CPU usage of the node processes) and your website is protected by Cloudflare, you may get 524 response from Cloudflare when it gets 503 or 500 error response from the server.
>
> ```
> Here is an example of processes per thread ID and CPU usage for each process:
> 2157 2179 1066 0% lsnode:/home/lynxkiko/forums/luaparse/
> 2157 2178 1066 32% lsnode:/home/lynxkiko/forums/luaparse/
> 2157 2177 1066 33% lsnode:/home/lynxkiko/forums/luaparse/
> 2157 2176 1066 32% lsnode:/home/lynxkiko/forums/luaparse/
> 2157 2175 1066 32% lsnode:/home/lynxkiko/forums/luaparse/
> 2157 2174 1066 0% lsnode:/home/lynxkiko/forums/luaparse/
> 2157 2157 1066 57% lsnode:/home/lynxkiko/forums/luaparse/
> ```
>
> As you can see, the LiteSpeed node process of `/home/lynxkiko/forums/luaparse/` is consuming a lot of CPU. We may recommend to enable debug mode and make sure that no one is abusing your application by creating requests that are CPU-intensive.

I have debugged my application over the period of 2-3 days and have no clue on why this is happening.

I thought It's happening because I am not closing the response, But I was closing it and I have added another code to cut of the TCP Connection after I am done with the client. `res.set("Connection", "close");`

So this is how my code follows

I am using luamin/luaparse to make an application that can optimize lua files and minify them and return back to the client.

```
const http = require('http');
var projectDir = __dirname;
const luaparse = require(projectDir + '/vendor/luaparse');
const luamin = require(projectDir + '/vendor/luamin');

function getTransformedCode(code) {
    let callbacks = [];


    const parsedCode = luaparse.parse(code);

    let changedCallbacks = [];
    parsedCode.body.forEach((element) => {
        const response = parseElement(element, callbacks, code, changedCallbacks);
        code = response[0];
        changedCallbacks = response[1]
    });
    var content = luamin.optimize(code);
    content = luamin.minify(content);
    //var content = code;
    return {
        content, callbacks
    }
}

function generateGuid() {
    var result, i, j;
    result = '';
    for (j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
        if (j == 8 || j == 12 || j == 16 || j == 20)
            result = result + '-';
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toString(16).toUpperCase();
        result = result + i;
    }
    return result;
}

function splice(str, start, delCount, newSubStr) {
    return str.slice(0, start) + newSubStr + str.slice(start + Math.abs(delCount));
}

function parseElement(element, callbacks, code, alreadyChanged) {
    // Replace all global 'local' variable names with something unique
    if (element.type === 'FunctionDeclaration') {
        // Rewrite functions to be local
        if (element.isLocal === false) {
            code = code.replace(new RegExp("function.*" + element.identifier.name), "local function " + element.identifier.name);
        }
    } else if (element.type === 'CallStatement' && element.expression.type === 'CallExpression') {
        let expression = element.expression;
        if (!expression.base || !expression.base.base) {
            return [code, alreadyChanged];
        }

        // Handle callbacks.Register
        if (expression.base.base.name === 'callbacks' && expression.base.identifier.name === 'Register') {
            // If we already have a unique callback ID, replace it, otherwise add it
            if (expression.arguments[1].type === 'StringLiteral') {
                callbacks.push([expression.arguments[0].value, expression.arguments[1].value]);
            } else {
                if (!alreadyChanged.includes(expression.arguments[0].raw)) {
                    var re = new RegExp(expression.arguments[0].raw, 'g');
                    while ((match = re.exec(code)) != null) {
                        let uniqueId = "C" + generateGuid().replace(/-/g, '').substr(0, 10);
                        code = splice(code, re.lastIndex, 0, ',"' + uniqueId + '"');
                        callbacks.push([expression.arguments[0].value, uniqueId]);
                    }
                }
                alreadyChanged.push(expression.arguments[0].raw);
            }
        }
    }
    return [code, alreadyChanged];
}

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        var body = '';

        req.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;

            // Too much POST data, kill the connection!
            // 1e6 === 1 * Math.pow(10, 6) === 1 * 1000000 ~~~ 1MB
            if (body.length > 1e6)
                req.connection.destroy();
        });

        req.on('end', function () {
            var code = getTransformedCode(body);
            res.end(JSON.stringify(code));
            res.set("Connection", "close");
        });
    } else {
        var message = 'It works!\n' + '\n',
            version = 'NodeJS ' + process.versions.node + '\n',
            response = [message, version].join('\n');
        res.end(response);
        res.set("Connection", "close");
    }
});
server.listen();
```

The code is working perfectly fine, but the problem raises when it stops responding then I have to manually restart the node.js application for it to work for a hour and break again, I need this application up 24/7 since I deliver the response over PHP

Comment: Have you tried just logging the start and the end of every request?

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer Nope, I am using a2hosting nodejs application manager and don't have a lot of freedom